# How can I use a variable from one function in another?

Tags: c, function

Is this possible?

Let's say I have this function:

```
void init_datastructure()
{
    struct record *head;
}
```

and then I have the main function

```
int main()
{
  init_datastructure();
}
```

Now if I want to use head in the main function, how can I do this? For example, how can I set head = NULL?

Comment: Create in `main` and pass by reference? "It depends" is a better answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Define the variable outside any of the functions:

```
static struct record *m_head;

void init_datastructure()
{
    m_head = ...
}

int main()
{
    struct record *p;

    init_datastructure();

    for (p = m_head; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        // ...

}
```

This will cause the  variable to live in the program's data section.

Note that I've marked the variable `static`. This means it will only be visible inside of this `.c` file, and not any others.  Also, as a matter of convention, I've prefixed its name with `m_` (indicating it is a "module" variable). This helps distinguish it from local variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches.

1. Use a global variable. A global variable can be used anywhere in the program. But most of the time this is not good.
2. Declare `*head` in the `main` function, then pass it to the `init_datastructure` function. For example

   ```
   void init_datastructure(record *head)
   {
        head = NULL;
   }

   int main()
   {
       struct record *head;
       init_datastructure(&head);
   }
   ```